# looping xml with xquery

Tags: xml, xquery, osb

I have a requirement to loop over xml and to replace string placeholders with values from xml file,

```
<ns0:parameters>
        <ns0:parameter>
            <ns1:paramName>P_1</ns1:paramName>
            <ns1:paramValue>paramValue_1</ns1:paramValue>
        </ns0:parameter>
        <ns0:parameter>
            <ns1:paramName>P_2</ns1:paramName>
            <ns1:paramValue>paramValue_2</ns1:paramValue>
        </ns0:parameter>
    </ns0:parameters>
```

the text will be in the following form

```
Welcome to P_1, this is your first P_2
```

so, we have to update the place holders in text (P_1 and P_2) with their value from the xml, so how we can do this using XQuery

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the `analyze-string()` function to split the text into parts that match the placeholder P_n and parts that don't; then process the result of the function as follows:

- For a non-matching text fragment, copy it to the output
- For a placeholder `$p`, replace it with `//ns0:parameter[ns1:paramName=$p]/ns1:paramValue`

The `analyze-string()` function requires XQuery 3.0. With 1.0 it's going to be a bit more difficult

Comment: but in my case I have to use XQuery 1.0, as we worked on old oracle ServiceBus version which not support XQuery 3.0

Comment: If you're constrained to use old versions of a technology, it saves everyone time if you say so upfront. Sorry, I don't have time to work out an XQ 1.0 solution - as I say, it ain't gonna be easy.

Answer (score 0):

For the XQUERY 1.0 use the loop to find the array position for

{
        For  $parameters $counter in $body/ns0:parameter

```
    Welcome to  $parameters/ns0:parameter[1][data(ns1:paramName)] this is your first 
    $parameters/ns0:parameter[$counter + 1][data(ns1:paramName)]P_2
```

}

Kindly can test

Use the counter variable to find the loop sequence.